# Reading files with ifstream not working after several file reads

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, ifstream

So I have written this application for the raspberry pi to play around with RFID tags. 
Anyway, the point of it is that a tag comes near the sensor, I read the tag and then I open a file containing the tags and the settings of the individual using an ifstream.

Here's the code:

```
bool Config::isTagInConfig(std::string tagID)
{
    /// Opens humans.cfg file and checks if tag is inside.
    std::ifstream file(PATH);
    std::string str;
    std::string delimiter = "\t";

    while (std::getline(file, str))
    {
        /// Since the tagID is always the first column, then the next line
        /// strictly obtains the tagID ALWAYS.
        std::string file_tagID = str.substr(0, str.find(delimiter));
        if (tagID == file_tagID)
        {
                file.close();
                return true;

        }
    }

    std::cout << tagID << " not found in Config file..." << std::endl;
    file.close();
    /// Consider adding a helper here, to add unknown tags.
    return false;
}
```

The code works fine for the first few hours, but after a while for some reason the file cannot be read...
I keep getting the message the the tag id was not found in the Config file.

I have tried searching why this would happen. I used to not have the line 'file.close()' but I recently changed that, yet the bug persists.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you for reading!

Comment: You wouldn't even need to call close, because RAII is amazing. I would guess it is a problem with the system, the C++ code looks fine to me.

Comment: Damn. That explains why it didn't do anything.
Hmmm any ideas on how I could figure out what's going on?

Comment: Oh, to figure the thing out you could use the bits of the fstream (goot, eof, bad, fail) though that will not tell you what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem, where ifstream no longer worked after running the program for awhile. It seemed it was no longer working after too many files were opened, even though I was also calling file.close(). It turned out I had an fopen() elsewhere in the program without an fclose().  I would check anywhere else you are opening files and make sure they are also being closed.